# AspNet Core 2.0 / IdentityServer4 - EntityFrameworkStore, UserManager and Authorization attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I've stumbled on this issue and this might be more of a configuration problem on my end but it's been a week and I wasn't able to solve this.

The scenario is; on my Client API startup.cs I have the

```
services.AddIdentity<TUser,TRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<context>();
```

Initially I don't have any problem at first, my nightmare started when I decided on adding and using policy(ies) and using `UserManager` in my ApiController using `[Authorize(Policy = "GivenPolicy")]` work if I remove the `services.AddIdentity`..... code.

Of course I can live with that but one of my API controller need is for me to use the `UserManager` which will not resolve if I don't have the `services.AddIdentity().AddEntityFrameworkStores()`.

I hope someone can help me on resolving this issue. TIA.

Comment: Could you highlight what goes wrong? An error message? What fails exactly?

Comment: Also please provide which version of ASP.Net Core you are using, as Authentication configuration has changed significantly.

Comment: @janpieter_z okay problem is when I use the services.AddIdentity<TUser,TRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<context>(); in the Startup.cs the [Authorize] attribute is not working meaning even if i'm authenticated I cant access an API controller, but UserManager<User> is being resolve/injected properly, my problem is I need to be able to use the [Authorize] attribute and the UserManager at the same time.

Comment: @tverboon I'm using .Netcore 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after so many days 
if ever someone encountered the same problem/issue that I have you can refer on this link:

[.Net Core 2.0 Web API using JWT - Adding Identity breaks the JWT authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323844/net-core-2-0-web-api-using-jwt-adding-identity-breaks-the-jwt-authentication)

PS: Not sure how to make this post as a link or something.

Anyway, happy coding guys.