# How do I dependency inject SignInManager?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a WebAPI app which I'm using a 3rd party authenticator  (Firebase authentication).

I have the authentication working but once the user has logged into my server, I'd like to save credentials and user data into my ASP.NET Identity tables.

I seem to be able to use the UserManager to create accounts if I call this line in my Startup.cs file

```
services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
                   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

This allows me to add UserManager in my constructor without adding all the login pages and the default cookie authentication scheme I'd normally get if I called AddIdentity()

However, when I add SignInManager in my constructor like this

```
public ValuesController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
```

I still seem to be getting this error.

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[mvcWithAuth.Data.ApplicationUser]'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'testWebAPIFB.Controllers.ValuesController'.

This seems to mean that AddIdentityCore doesn't add SignInManager. How do I add SignInManager as a class to be dependency injected?

Answer (score 7):

> This seems to mean that AddIdentityCore doesn't add SignInManager.

That's true.If you check the source code of [Addidentity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/8ef14785a4a1e416189ca1137eb13f43c2f4349d/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L92) and [AddIdentityCore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/9b385180a9abcb264507efc23279f083bfc50520/src/Core/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), you will find that `AddIdentityCore` registers the `UserManager` only without `SignInManager`

To add `SignInManager` with `AddIdentityCore`, you could try:

```
IdentityBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>();

builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);

builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Refer to [.Net Core 2.0 Web API using JWT - Adding Identity breaks the JWT authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323844/net-core-2-0-web-api-using-jwt-adding-identity-breaks-the-jwt-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

Using this code will work for you.

In your controller

```
private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;

public SomeController(
        SignInManager<User> signInManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
```

In your Startup.cs

```
        services
            .AddIdentity<User, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 0):

SignInManager is registered by of `AddIdentity`. `AddIdentityCore` only register UserManger.

in you code use,

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Edit: To make JWTBearer as default authentication scheme, Here is what I did,

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(/*options => Db Config*/);
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            cfg.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            cfg.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            cfg.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            cfg.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            cfg.SaveToken = true;
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new
                SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"]))
            };

        });
```

Comment: so the only problem is AddIdentity overrides the default authentication scheme to cookie authentication and I'm using JWT tokens to authenticate. So then I just get an authentication error and then re-directs me to the Account/Login page.

Comment: For that you can set the default authentication scheme to JWT

Answer (score 0):

You should use **AddIdentity** because the SignInManager is not registered in DI Container

like

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
```

or

Register the SignInManager

```
services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```