# Can I use the Authorize attribute filtering by Roles and Claims when using ASP.NET Identity and JWT authentication from external providers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

So I’m using firebase for authentication on my WebAPI app. It gets a JWT token and then authenticates it and then puts the claims in the `HttpContext.User`.

My only problem is I just want to use Firebase Authentication for authentication, not for authorization. I want to use ASP.NET Identity for this.

so right now, when someone connects to my server, I’ll check if they don’t have an account, if not I will create one for them.

```
var name = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "user_id").Value;

ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(name);

if (user == null)
{
    user = new ApplicationUser(name);
    await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);                
}
```

So this works, and now there is a record in the ASPNetUsers against the user and later on, I can give it Claims and Roles against whatever business rules I’d like.

However, my question is, previously, when I’ve used ASP.NET Identity I’ve been able to leverage all of the built-in features like the Authorize attribute to do my authorization.

So if both authentication and authorization is done using ASP.NET Identity, I can write

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```

Obviously, that won’t work with external authentication because `HttpContext.User` is the Firebase Authenticated user, not the corresponding ASP.NET Identity user that has the Administrator role.

Is there a way to customize the existing Authorize attribute to configure it to somehow convert my firebase token into an ASP.NET Identity so that it would recognize the roles and claims it has or if I wanted to do all this through middleware, am I going to need to write my own authorize attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I've finally figured it out. It seems there's a couple of events you can intercept during the Jwt authentication process. In particular, there is an OnTokenValidated event.

```
services.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    ...

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {

        OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
        {
            // 1. grabs the user id from firebase
            var name = ctx.Principal.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "user_id").Value;

            // Get userManager out of DI
            var _userManager = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

            // 2. retrieves the roles that the user has
            ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(name);
            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            //3.  adds the role as a new claim 
            ClaimsIdentity identity = ctx.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (identity != null)
            {
                foreach (var role in userRoles)
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
                }
            }

        }

    };
});
```

So what the code above is saying

1. once the token is authenticated, take the userId from the
   external provider
2. Go into ASP.NET Identity and find the user and
   the roles for that user [remember in my original question, I insert a user
   into ASP.NET Identity table when they first log in, I'm just grabbing that user]
3. Insert the roles of that user back into the ClaimsIdentity

The result is that when the Authorise attribute runs, it'll include the AspNET Identity Roles of the user in the check and I can do something like below and it'll check the role.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the authorize attribute with some modification,

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,Roles = "Administrator")]
```

But if you want to make it a default scheme, then refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57177320/3613702)
Here is a summary, Add it to he Startup class,

```
services.AddAuthentication(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
```

Comment: Sorry I should've been clear. I can get the Authorize attribute to work on its own when it's just [Authorize] because all that's saying is if the default authentication scheme (JWT) gives me access then let me in, but I can't say [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] because although I can get in using the JWT token, it doesn't actually know which ASP.NET Identity user I am and what ASP.NET Identity roles it's associated with. That's why I usually use _userManager.FindByNameAsync(name) to find that out.

Comment: I can keep doing that, but preferably I'd like to do this all through middleware. I also don't want to write new code if the Authorise attribute already has some support for it somehow.

Comment: In that case the link that I have given should work, Did you try that? Initially I thought the other question was also asked by you. 
Edit: Sorry I have updated the link, and the other question from you indeed

Comment: Thanks Code - really appreciate the help. I did have a look at the link but I'm not sure how it relates. I've already gotten JWTBearer working as the default authentication scheme. The authorise attribute works - it lets me in only when I have a valid token. I don't think my problem is the authentication scheme - it's the fact that Authorise attribute can't filter by Roles or claims because they are stored against the ASP.NET Identity and i'm authenticating using my JWT identity.

Comment: It doesn't know my ASP.NET Identity user until I extract it out of the HttpContext like this _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "user_id").Value; and then search the database with the ID _userManager.FindByNameAsync(name);

Comment: I could use those two lines and write logic checking to see if its in the right roles etc. at the start of every endpoint - that would work - but I'd like to put all of this into the middleware so I don't need to worry about it. In order to do that, I would need to write my own custom Authorise attribute that would do the extraction between the JWT token and convert to ASP.NET identity and check roles, claims etc. - I was just hoping that since JWT authentication is so common, the existing authorise attribute might cover it.

Comment: Still I believe role based filtering should just work OOB. If not done already modify  `services.AddIdentity<User, ApplicationRole>` to include role.then attribute should just start working. I believe the JWT claims token also holds the Role information.

Comment: Normally, the JWT token would hold the Role information but my JWT token is from an external authentication provider and has no idea what my roles are for the user which are stored in the ASP.NET Identity tables. Anyhow, I was probably really unclear explaining it but i've figured it out - check out my solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204002/279911

Answer (score 0):

I think this should make your Authorization work:

1. You have to make ClaimsPrincipal the base class of your ApplicationUser class. 
   (ClaimsPrincipal implements the IPrincipal interface)
2. Then inside your ApplicationUser class implement/override the **IsInRole** method that comes with the ClaimsPrincipal (base) class. [IsInRole official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2). The role argument of the method will contain the **value of the Roles property** on the AuthorizeAtribute that you specify.
3. Set the **HttpContext.User** using your instance of type ApplicationUser. (explanation: Setting the property User on Httpcontext allows you to specify (=customize) the user of the current request **within asp.net request processing**)

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite understanding. My ApplicationUser is inheriting from IdentityUser. That allows me to extend the AspNetUsers table. How would I be able to run UserManager.CreateAsync if ApplicationUser wasn't inheriting from IdentityUser?

Comment: In that case make your own type (ex:xxxUser) that resembles ApplicationUser and that inhertis from ClaimsPrincipal. Also provide a method that maps an ApplicationUser to your type (ex:xxxUser)

Comment: Hi hannes, thanks for your responses. I think I explained it really badly, but this is what I finally did which worked. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204002/279911